# how to make the function return a value under this situation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use `ui.confirm` like this:

```
if(ui.confirm('content')){
    //do something
}else{
    //do something
}
```

ui :

```
var ui = {
    confirm:function(content){
        //...            
        $(".btn-success").click(function(){
            //when I click this button , ui.confirm return true
        });
        $(".btn-warning").click(function(){
            //when I click this button , ui.confirm return false
        });
    }
}
```

Although I have another incompletion solution like this:

```
var ui = {
    confirm:function(content,callback1,callback2){
        //...

        $(".btn-success").click(function(){
            //execute callback1
        });
        $(".btn-warning").click(function(){
            //execute callback2
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't: go with the async programming model, not against it. I recommend using [Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)/A (jQuery [Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) are sufficient) and not "callbacks".

Comment: Well, you can't return the result from a function launching an asynchronous action.

Comment: @user2864740 promises might be a too hard path for a beginner.

Comment: @dystroy That's the perfect time to be introduced! But then I'm biased I guess :|

Comment: @user2864740 Even with promises, you need to understand callbacks and asynchronous programming. That should be the first step. And don't forget that as long as ES6 isn't available in your browser, using promises involves managing the dependency to an external library.

Comment: @dystroy Well, as you said , promises might by too hard to me (a freshman) , but I need to study it! ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return a meaningful value from `confirm` because the button clicks are *asynchronous*. This means that the button clicks will (may) occur "at some point in the future", but the function must "return immediately".

The solution in JavaScript is to use the asynchronous programming model through-and-through once this situation is encountered. While [callbacks](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) are the building-blocks of such asynchronous operations, I prefer to use Promises when I can.

As such, and because dystroy doesn't think I should ;-), I'll present an approach using [Promises/A](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) (jQuery *1.9+* [Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) work just fine and come "for free" with jQuery).

```
function uiConfirm (msg) {
   var action = $.Deferred();

   // Note: On the button clicks the dialog should be closed as a Promise can only
   // be resolved/rejected once; Promises are really good for execution flow
   // management (see `then`), but are not as general as simple callbacks.
   $(".btn-success").click(function(){
       action.resolve("okay");
   });
   $(".btn-warning").click(function(){
       // Depending upon semantics, this could `reject` the Promise, but I think
       // it's cleaner to just resolve it with a different discriminator value 
       // in this case.
       action.resolve("cancel");
   });

   // uiConfirm returns immediately (before the clicks),
   // but returns a Promise/Deferred that can be resolved (or rejected) later
   // in response to a button click.
   return action;
}

uiConfirm("Do you like Cheese?")
   .then(function (value) {
      // This code runs when a button has been clicked
      alert("Action: " + value);
   });

// This code runs right after uiConfirm returns (before any clicks)
// because uiConfirm is asynchronous or "non-blocking"
```

Comment: I don't think you shouldn't present promise, you should, they'll be more and more important in the js world, I think OP should be warned that using them in the browser today aren't the easy or natural path.

Comment: Aren't easy or natural? Whoa, that's harsh fighting words! That being said, I entirely agree that the OP should understand first-class functions and callbacks (and be able to use them with/without Promises).

Comment: I mean in the general case (that everybody must master). When you use jquery you have their promise system of course.

Comment: @dystroy I'm in jQuery 99% of my time :| - I advocate jQuery Deferred only insofar as it is "for free". If not using jQuery, I'd likely pick a different implementation - you are correct in that Promises are (currently) non-native, and that callbacks are essential to master.

Answer (score 2):

not possible using async functions

you need to do something like:

```
ui.confirm('content', function() {
    //do something
}, function() {
    //do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it exactly like that. You will have to supply a callback function to "do something" when either of the click events occur. You cannot "return" from these events to a previously executed state.

```
var ui = {
    confirm:function(content,callback1,callback2){
        $(".btn-success").click(function(){
            callback1();
        });
        $(".btn-warning").click(function(){
            callback2();
        });
    }
}

ui.confirm('content', function() {
  //do something
  alert("success");
}, function() {
  //do something else
  alert("WARNING");
})
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xvbL5/1/

Comment: Should generally use `fn()` (instead of `fn.call()`) if not supplying a specific context.